# How to form multiple sub-dataframes based on unique date intervals in r

Tags: r, date, datetime, split

This is my transaction data.

```
data

id          from    to          date        amount  
<int>       <fctr>  <fctr>      <date>      <dbl>
19521       6644    6934        2005-01-01  700.0
19524       6753    8456        2005-01-01  600.0
19523       9242    9333        2005-01-01  1000.0
…           …       …           …           …
1056317     7819    7454        2010-12-31  60.2
1056318     6164    7497        2010-12-31  107.5
1056319     7533    7492        2010-12-31  164.1
```

For each unique date in `date` column, I want to determine a date interval, which is the last 6 month prior to that specified unique date. For example, to determine the last 6 month period prior to the date `"2005-01-01"`, I subtract 180 days from `"2005-01-01"` to get `"2004-07-05"`. Hence, the interval `"2004-07-05"-"2005-01-01"` is the last 6 month period prior to the date `"2005-01-01"`. So, I create a new column `date_minus_180` accordingly as follows:

```
id          from    to          date        date_minus_180    amount  
<int>       <fctr>  <fctr>      <date>      <date>            <dbl>
19521       6644    6934        2005-01-01  2004-07-05        700.0
19522       9843    9115        2005-01-01  2004-07-05        900.0
19523       9242    9333        2005-01-01  2004-07-05        1000.0
19524       6753    8456        2005-01-01  2004-07-05        600.0
19525       7075    6510        2005-01-02  2004-07-06        400.0
19526       8685    7207        2005-01-02  2004-07-06        1100.0
19527       5513    6046        2005-01-03  2004-07-07        600.0
19528       6340    7047        2005-01-03  2004-07-07        1100.0
19529       6042    6213        2005-01-03  2004-07-07        200.0
19530       5587    9493        2005-01-03  2004-07-07        800.0
...
```

Now what I want to do is to get sub-dataframes by splitting the data based on each unique date intervals. That is, considering the first date interval `"2004-07-05"-"2005-01-01"`, we'll have a sub-dataframe containing observations where the date in `date` column is in the range of this date interval. Since the date in my data is in ascending order, thus the very first date is `"2005-01-01"`. So, the first sub-dataframe will consist of the first 4 observations, since the date `"2005-01-01"` in the `date` column of these observations is in the range of the interval `"2004-07-05"-"2005-01-01"`. Similarly, considering the second date interval `"2004-07-06"-"2005-01-02"`, we'll have a sub-dataframe containing observations where the date in the `date` column is in the range of this date interval. So, the second sub-dataframe will consist of the first 6 observations since the dates `"2005-01-01"` and `"2005-01-02"` are in the range of the interval `"2004-07-06"-"2005-01-02"`. So, continuing in this manner, how can I form multiple sub-dataframes based on these specified date intervals?

Let's again consider the interval `"2004-07-05"-"2005-01-01"`. For this particular interval, we can subset the data as follows:

```
data[data$date >= "2004-07-05" & data$date <= "2005-01-01",]
```

giving the output:

```
id          from    to          date        date_minus_180    amount  
<int>       <fctr>  <fctr>      <date>      <date>            <dbl>
19521       6644    6934        2005-01-01  2004-07-05        700.0
19522       9843    9115        2005-01-01  2004-07-05        900.0
19523       9242    9333        2005-01-01  2004-07-05        1000.0
19524       6753    8456        2005-01-01  2004-07-05        600.0
```

So, how to subset the data in just one go for all the intervals?

a sample from the data:

```
structure(list(id = c(18529L, 13742L, 9913L, 956L, 2557L, 1602L, 
18669L, 35900L, 48667L, 51341L, 53713L, 60126L, 60545L, 65113L, 
66783L, 83324L, 87614L, 88898L, 89874L, 94765L, 100277L, 101587L, 
103444L, 108414L, 113319L, 121516L, 126607L, 130170L, 131771L, 
135002L, 149431L, 157403L, 157645L, 158831L, 162597L, 162680L, 
163901L, 165044L, 167082L, 168562L, 168940L, 172578L, 173031L, 
173267L, 177507L, 179167L, 182612L, 183499L, 188171L, 189625L, 
193940L, 198764L, 199342L, 200134L, 203328L, 203763L, 204733L, 
205651L, 209672L, 210242L, 210979L, 214532L, 214741L, 215738L, 
216709L, 220828L, 222140L, 222905L, 226133L, 226527L, 227160L, 
228193L, 231782L, 232454L, 233774L, 237836L, 237837L, 238860L, 
240223L, 245032L, 246673L, 247561L, 251611L, 251696L, 252663L, 
254410L, 255126L, 255230L, 258484L, 258485L, 259309L, 259910L, 
260542L, 262091L, 264462L, 264887L, 264888L, 266125L, 268574L, 
272959L), from = c("5370", "5370", "5370", "8605", "5370", "6390", 
"5370", "5370", "8934", "5370", "5635", "6046", "5680", "8026", 
"9037", "5370", "7816", "8046", "5492", "8756", "5370", "9254", 
"5370", "5370", "7078", "6615", "5370", "9817", "8228", "8822", 
"5735", "7058", "5370", "8667", "9315", "6053", "7990", "8247", 
"8165", "5656", "9261", "5929", "8251", "5370", "6725", "5370", 
"6004", "7022", "7442", "5370", "8679", "6491", "7078", "5370", 
"5370", "5370", "5658", "5370", "9296", "8386", "5370", "5370", 
"5370", "9535", "5370", "7541", "5370", "9621", "5370", "7158", 
"8240", "5370", "5370", "8025", "5370", "5370", "5370", "6989", 
"5370", "7059", "5370", "5370", "5370", "9121", "5608", "5370", 
"5370", "7551", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "9163", "9362", 
"6072", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370"), to = c("9356", 
"5605", "8567", "5370", "5636", "5370", "8933", "8483", "5370", 
"7626", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "9676", "5370", 
"5370", "5370", "5370", "9105", "5370", "9772", "6979", "5370", 
"5370", "7564", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "8744", 
"5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", 
"5370", "5370", "7318", "5370", "8433", "5370", "5370", "5370", 
"7122", "5370", "5370", "5370", "8566", "6728", "9689", "5370", 
"8342", "5370", "5370", "5614", "5596", "5953", "5370", "7336", 
"5370", "7247", "5370", "7291", "5370", "5370", "6282", "7236", 
"5370", "8866", "8613", "9247", "5370", "6767", "5370", "9273", 
"7320", "9533", "5370", "5370", "8930", "9343", "5370", "9499", 
"7693", "7830", "5392", "5370", "5370", "5370", "7497", "8516", 
"9023", "7310", "8939"), date = structure(c(12934, 13000, 13038, 
13061, 13099, 13113, 13117, 13179, 13238, 13249, 13268, 13296, 
13299, 13309, 13314, 13391, 13400, 13404, 13409, 13428, 13452, 
13452, 13460, 13482, 13493, 13518, 13526, 13537, 13542, 13544, 
13596, 13616, 13617, 13626, 13633, 13633, 13639, 13642, 13646, 
13656, 13660, 13664, 13667, 13669, 13677, 13686, 13694, 13694, 
13707, 13716, 13725, 13738, 13739, 13746, 13756, 13756, 13756, 
13761, 13769, 13770, 13776, 13786, 13786, 13786, 13791, 13799, 
13806, 13813, 13817, 13817, 13817, 13822, 13829, 13830, 13836, 
13847, 13847, 13847, 13852, 13860, 13866, 13871, 13878, 13878, 
13878, 13882, 13883, 13883, 13887, 13887, 13888, 13889, 13890, 
13891, 13895, 13896, 13896, 13899, 13905, 13909), class = "Date"), 
    amount = c(24.4, 7618, 21971, 5245, 2921, 8000, 169.2, 71.5, 
    14.6, 4214, 14.6, 13920, 14.6, 24640, 1600, 261.1, 16400, 
    3500, 2700, 19882, 182, 14.6, 16927, 25653, 3059, 2880, 9658, 
    4500, 12480, 14.6, 1000, 3679, 34430, 12600, 14.6, 19.2, 
    4900, 826, 3679, 2100, 38000, 79, 11400, 21495, 3679, 200, 
    14.6, 100.6, 3679, 5300, 108.9, 3679, 2696, 7500, 171.6, 
    14.6, 99.2, 2452, 3679, 3218, 700, 69.7, 14.6, 91.5, 2452, 
    3679, 2900, 17572, 14.6, 14.6, 90.5, 2452, 49752, 3679, 1900, 
    14.6, 870, 85.2, 2452, 3679, 1600, 540, 14.6, 14.6, 79, 210, 
    2452, 28400, 720, 180, 420, 44289, 489, 3679, 840, 2900, 
    150, 870, 420, 14.6)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Map` :

```
data$date_minus_180 <- data$date - 180

result <- Map(function(x, y) data[data$date >=y & data$date <= x,], 
                             data$date, data$date_minus_180)
```

and similarly with `lapply` without the need of `date_minus_180` column.

```
result <- lapply(data$date, function(x) 
                 data[data$date >= (x-180) & data$date <= x,])
```

Comment: These functions do not perform well on a large dataset. Is there a way to solve this by data.table?

Comment: You want to split the data in multiple dataframes, I am not sure if `data.table` would help here. :/